# php dbase error when opening a .dbf file

Tags: php, apache2, dbf, dbase

I'm trying to use the dbase library in php5.3 to open a .dbf file.  I've got the dbase.so library installed and active on my php5 build and I'm executing the following code:

```
$db = dbase_open('CMX.dbf', 0);
if( $db ){
    echo 'success';
    dbase_close($db);
}
```

Where CMX.dbf is a Visual FoxPro9 data table and is located in the same directory as the executing script with read/write/execute permissions enabled.

The following is an exert from `/var/log/apache2/error.log`:

```
PHP Warning:  dbase_open(): unable to open database CMX.dbf in /var/www/test.php on
```

line 28

As this error/warning is not very descriptive, I'm having issues tracking down the root cause.  Can anyone help with this?

Comment: From the manual, there is not more information available but just that it failed to open the database. Permission and/or file-format comes to mind.

Answer (score 0):

Not positive about PHP, nor Apache, but typically, when trying to connect to database files (or Foxpro), the typical approach would be to have a CONNECTION to a PATH, then perform a query against the name of the table....

Comment: thanks for the reply but dbase uses the dbase_open() function to establish the connection; there is not a dbase_connect() function available within the list of dbase commands.  See http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.dbase.php

Answer (score 0):

Try this (in foxpro):

```
use cmx.dbf
copy to cmx_php.dbf type fox2x
```

I was having a similar problem where some dbs would open and others would not. This allowed me to access the db with `php/dbase.so`

I found the info [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.dbase-open.php) in the comments section.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
$db_path = "CMX.dbf";

$db = dbase_open($db_path, 0) // 0=ReadOnly, 1=WriteOnly 2=ReadWrite 
       or die("Error! Could not open dbase database file '$db_path'.");

if( $db ){
    echo 'success';
    dbase_close($db);
}
```

Comment: what's the difference with the initial question ?